# Python: Logging messages into json in one parent dict/list

Tags: python, json, logging

I was using the [jsonLogger](https://github.com/madzak/python-json-logger) library

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
#logHandler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
logHandler = logging.FileHandler('reuben.json')
formatter = jsonlogger.JsonFormatter()
logHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(logHandler)
logger.setLevel('DEBUG')

logger.debug({"message": "Successfully installed host", "host": "host1", "status": "success"})
logger.debug({"message": "Failed to install host", "host": "host2", "status": "failed"})
```

And this code is giving me the json in the given below format:

```
{"message": "Successfully installed host", "status": "success", "host": "host1"}
{"message": "Failed to install host", "status": "failed", "host": "host2"}
```

So it looks two different dicts. Is it possible to log all the messages in one parent dict or list ? I mean :

```
[{"message": "Successfully installed host", "status": "success", "host": "host1"},
    {"message": "Failed to install host", "status": "failed", "host": "host2"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so. If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/madzak/python-json-logger/blob/master/src/pythonjsonlogger/jsonlogger.py#L104) of the formater (line 104) you can see that the `log_record` variable is local. It is created each time `format()` is executed.  It does not hold any previous messages.

The workaround would be to create a list of messages to store and than write is as a whole. But it does not seem as a good solution.

```
log_list = []

log_list.append({"message": "Successfully installed host", "host": "host1", "status": "success"})
log_list.append({"message": "Successfully installed host", "host": "host1", "status": "success"})


logger.debug(log_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to read the log file line by line and convert to json_string using json.loads.

```
with open(filename,"r") as log_obj:
    logs = log_obj.readlines()
    for log in logs:
        json_string = json.loads(log)
        print(json_string)
```